# Object instantiation inside of switch revisited (c++)

Tags: c++, class, templates, switch-statement

I undestand that objects instantiated inside of a switch case or an if condition will cease to exist once that block of code has been left (as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395289/why-i-cant-instantiate-objects-inside-a-switch-case-block)). But what is then the right way to instantiate an object depending on e.g. user input? I believe one can see from the example what I'm (clumsily) trying to do:

```
class triangle
{
public:
    static const int dimension = 2;
};

class tetrahedron
{
public:
    static const int dimension = 3;
};

template<class T>
class element
{
    public:
    int getDimension()
    {
        return T::dimension;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int elementType;
    std::cout<< "Enter 1 for triangle or 2 for tet: " 
    std::cin >> elementType;

    switch(elementType)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            element<triangle> myElementFile;
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
            element<tetrahedron> myElementFile;
            break;
        }
    }
    // I want to use myElementFile further, but it does not exist here
    std::cout<< "The dimension is: " << myElementFile.getDimension(); //this won't work
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if the overall approach of using classes as "containers" for storing info about the different elements and then feeding them into a different class is optimal, but I should stick to it for now, because I was told to. :) I am new to c++ and OOP in general. Thank you for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case where you should use polymorphism.

There are two types of polymorphism:

1. Static, where you use templates and objects are generated during compilation
2. Dynamic, where you use inheritance and objects are generated on runtime

Both have pros and cons: http://www.cpptutor.com/static-polymorphism-and-dynamic-polymorphism-in-c++.htm

Static approach to your is nicely explained in Kerrek SB's answer.

If you want to create an object and store it for later, I rather recommend using dynamic approach:

```
enum Elements {
    triangle = 1,
    tetrahedron = 2
}

class Element {
    public:
       virtual int getDimension() = 0;
}

class Triangle : public Element {
    virtual int getDimension() { return 1;}
}

class Tetrahedron : public Element {        
    virtual int getDimension() { return 4;}
}

int main()
{
    Elements elementType;
    std::cout<< "Enter 1 for triangle or 2 for tet: " 
    std::cin >> elementType;


    Element* element = NULL;
    switch(elementType)
    {
    case triangle:
          element = new Triangle();
          break;
    case tetrahedron:
          element = new Tetrahedron();
          break;
    default:
          element = new Tetrahedron();
          break;
    };

    std::cout << "The dimension is: " << element->getDimension() << "\n";
    delete element;

}
```

Comment: +1 for a more complete answer than mine!

Comment: Wouldn't I have to use `element->getDimension()` rather than `element.getDimension()` because `element` is a pointer? That way and after including semicolons after the class definitions I got it to work properly.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 3):

The overall solution is to factor your code.

```
template <typename T>
void process_thing(T const & t)
{
    std::cout << "The dimension is: " << t.getDimension() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    switch (condition)
    {
    case Triangle:
      {
          process_thing(element<triangle>());
          break;
      }
    case Tetrahedron:
      { 
          process_thing(element<tetrahedron>());
          break;
      }
    default:
      {
          // ...
      }
    };
}
```

Don't do everything in one function, but separate functional components into distinct pieces of code and compose them logically.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to fully embrace object-oriented programming, and create a base class Element, and then create derived classes triangle and tetrahedron that inherit Element. You can then instantiate the Element as triangle or tetrahedron in the switch statement:

```
// define base class and derived classes here -- 
// any good book on oo programming will guide you.
//

int main()
{
int     choice = 1;
Element *element;

switch (choice)
{
case 1:
    element = new Triangle ();
    break;

case 2:
    element = new Tetrahedron ();
    break;
}

// do stuff with element here:
std::cout << "Element has " << element.dimensions << "dimensions!" << std::endl;

delete element;
return 0;
}
```

Good luck!